# How to select rows with certain condition in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

We have the column `Title` with the values `[Mr, Miss, Dr, Major]`. I want to select rows whose value are only equal to `Mr`, `Miss`, or `Dr`. I wrote the following code:

```
train = train[train['Title'] in ['Dr', 'Miss', 'Mr']]
```

But I get the following error:

> To combine filtering conditions in Pandas, use bitwise operators ('&' and '|') not pure Python ones ('and' and 'or')

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `isin`

```
titles = ['Dr', 'Miss', 'Mr']
train.loc[train['Title'].isin(titles), :]
```

Answer (score 0):

For conditional operations in Pandas, the bitwise operators are used, instead of pure python operators. Read here for more : [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).  As such, the solution offered by @Eric suffices. However, you could use the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method, which allows a near english representation of ur search condition :

```
 train.query('Title in ["Dr","Miss","Mr"]')
```